# Moving specific files to two different locations

Tags: wildcards, file-copy, file-server

I am having a query regarding file separation in unix. Suppose in a unix directory there are multiple files with different names but having same extension. E.g.

```
/dir/AB_123yuu.pdf
/dir/SD_234ggj.pdf
/dir/AB_123jlhj.pdf
/dir/DE_373hhj.pdf
etc...
```

Now the requirement is to copy all the files beginning with name   `AB_123`   to `server1` and copy the remaining files to `server2` at the same time.

Comment: "At the same time"...?

Comment: Title says move, body says copy...?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `bash` use extended glob mechanism:

```
shopt -s extglob
cp ABC_123* /server1/
cp !(ABC_123*) /server2/
```

The `!(pattern)` will match everything **except** the given pattern.

---

Under `zsh` similar things would be

```
setopt extendedglob
cp AB_123* /server1/
cp *~AB_123* /server2/
```

or even simpler

```
cp ^AB_123* /server2/
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `extglob` option, and `rsync`

```
shopt -s extglob
rsync -a AB_123*    server1:/home/foo/files &
rsync -a !(AB_123*) server2:/home/foo/files &
```

See this question for more information,

- [How can I use inverse or negative wildcards when pattern matching in a unix/linux shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/216995/124486)

Answer (score 0):

Create two array

AR1: For files with AB_123*.pdf regex match

AR2: For files with extension *.pdf and without AB_123 prefix

Populate it with two find commands, and copy files to remote server with scp

---

```
AR1=()

AR2=()

for file in $(find /path -name AB_123*.pdf); do AR1+=($file); done

for file in $(find . -name *.pdf | grep -v /AB_123); do AR2+=($file); done

scp ${AR1[*]} username@server1:/remote/path

scp ${AR2[*]} username@server2:/remote/path
```

This is an example